# Explicit homeomorphism $D^p\times D^q \to D^{p+q}$ where $D^n$ is the unit closed disk in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $D^n$ denote the unit closed disk in $\Bbb R^n$. It is well-known that $D^p\times D^q$ is homeomorphic to $D^{p+q}$. Can we write the formula of such a homeomorphism explicitly? All I need is a well-defined continuous bijection $D^p\times D^q \to D^{p+q}$ (because the domain is compact and the target is Hausdorff), but I can't see where should I send $(x,y)\in D^p\times D^q$ to a point of $D^{p+q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x, y) \mapsto (x, y) \frac{\max(\|x\|, \|y\|)}{\|(x, y)\|}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint for one possible approach: Find a homeomorphism between $D^n$ and $[-1,1]^n$ in each dimension $n$. Then find a homeomorphism $$[-1,1]^p\times [-1,1]^q\to [-1,1]^{p+q}$$